# how do you webscrape if location of a data of interest changes? do you use keyword than indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, angular, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

site that will be webscraped: https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-cli/issues?state=all&per_page=1&page=1

```
import requests
import bs4
page_number=1
number=[]
state=[]
created_at=[]
closed_at=[]

while page_number<100:
  base_url=f'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-cli/issues?state=all&per_page=1&page={page_number}'
  result=requests.get(base_url)
  soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,'lxml')
  test_string=soup.select('p')[0].getText()[2:]
  my_list=test_string.split(',')
  number.append(my_list[8])
  state.append(my_list[29])
  created_at.append(my_list[35])
  closed_at.append(my_list[37])
  
  page_number=page_number+1
```

my data of interest are number, state, created_at,closed_at
when I print their lists, the results are incorrect probably because their index changes in other pages and I based the code for indexing just in the first page.

Answer (score 2):

No need to parse with beautifulsoup. The data comes in a nice json format. However, there is a rate limit  of 60 request per hour for the api.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

page_number=1
rows = []
while page_number<100:
  base_url=f'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-cli/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page={page_number}'
  response = requests.get(base_url)
  
  if response.status_code != 200:
      print('Response: %s' %response.status_code)
      break
  
  jsonData = response.json()
  
  rows += jsonData
  print(page_number)
  page_number=page_number+1
  
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
output = df[['number', 'state', 'created_at', 'closed_at']]
```

**Output sample:**

```
print(output)
   number state            created_at closed_at
0   23719  open  2022-08-10T09:38:18Z      None
1   23718  open  2022-08-10T09:20:48Z      None
2   23717  open  2022-08-10T08:56:29Z      None
3   23716  open  2022-08-10T08:13:01Z      None
4   23715  open  2022-08-10T07:08:05Z      None
5   23714  open  2022-08-09T23:36:26Z      None
6   23713  open  2022-08-09T22:44:22Z      None
7   23712  open  2022-08-09T22:11:42Z      None
8   23711  open  2022-08-09T20:22:43Z      None
```

Comment: I changed the url to show 100 per page instead of 1 to reduce the number of requests needed.
`page_number=1
rows = []

while requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-cli/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page={page_number}').json() != []:
  base_url=f'https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-cli/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page={page_number}'
  result=requests.get(base_url).json()
  
  rows += result
  #print(page_number)
  page_number=page_number+1

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df[['number', 'state', 'created_at', 'closed_at']]`

Comment: Ok edited the code for you above.